# Replacing images in Word 2000 doc

Tags: python, ms-word

I have a large `.doc` file with ~140 images in various formats (but mostly `PNG`). 
I would like to swap all the `PNG` images with `JPEG` (which would save me ~20MB, allegedly).

I have tried saving as a .docx and manipulating things with `Python-docx` and `docxtpl,` but can't really get anything to actually happen to the file. I am kinda at a standstill, and would rather not have to modify the doc manually.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: swap ? you mean convert ? or u totally swap with a new jpeg image ?

Comment: Well, if there's a way to convert in-place, that'd be great. But if not, replace will meet the requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I eventually figured out an "analog" solution in that I didn't really use a program...

1. I converted the .doc into a .docx using TextMaker
2. I unzipped the    docx into a separate directory unimaginatively called "docx"
3. The    picture files resided in docx\word\media where I used a program very
   similar to Ann's (above) to convert the PNG's to JPEG (same
   basename, different extension)
4. In the docx\word_rels dir, there is a file document.xml.rels that documents all     the relationships
   between rId#'s in the main document.xml and the media files (among
   other things)
5. Using my trusty text editor, I searched and replaced
   all the ".png" for ".jpeg"
6. After some housekeeping, I zipped it back
   into an actual docx, checked it in TextMaker, and saved it as a .doc
   file.
7. I fixed the minor formatting issues (99% bad numbering on
   lists), and the boss loves me. :D

If nothing else, this was a great introduction to the internal structure of docx's!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are able to place all the images into a folder, you can use the Pillow module to convert the format of each image:

```
from PIL import Image
from glob import glob

for f in glob("*.png"):
    Image.open(f).save(f.split('.')[0]+'.jpg')
```

This will save a converted version of all the `png` file of the same directory of the python file. If you want to convert other images, simply change the `glob("*.png")` to the right extension.

Comment: Thanks, but the real meat of the question is in the manipulation of the images in the Word doc. By saving as a .docx, I was able to access the media, and convert the png's to jpeg. Now how to re-insert them into the document...?